# Clojure style / idiom: creating maps and adding them to other maps

Tags: clojure, styles, idioms

I'm writing a Clojure programme to help me perform a security risk assessment (finally gotten fed-up with Excel).

I have a question on Clojure idiom and style.

To create a new record about an asset in a risk assessment I pass in the risk-assessment I'm currently working with (a map) and a bunch of information about the asset and my make-asset function creates the asset, adds it to the R-A and returns the new R-A.

```
(defn make-asset
  "Makes a new asset, adds it to the given risk assessment
  and returns the new risk assessment."
  [risk-assessment name description owner categories
   & {:keys [author notes confidentiality integrity availability]
      :or   {author "" notes "" confidentiality 3 integrity 3 availability 3}}]
  (let [ia-ref (inc (risk-assessment :current-ia-ref))]
    (assoc risk-assessment
      :current-ia-ref ia-ref
      :assets (conj (risk-assessment :assets)
                    {:ia-ref ia-ref
                     :name name
                     :desc description
                     :owner owner
                     :categories categories
                     :author author
                     :notes notes
                     :confidentiality confidentiality
                     :integrity integrity
                     :availability availability
                     :vulns []}))))
```

Does this look like a sensible way of going about it?

Could I make it more idiomatic, shorter, simpler?

Particular things I am thinking about are:

- should make-asset add the asset to the risk-assessment? (An asset is meaningless outside of a risk assessment).
- is there a simpler way of creating the asset; and
- adding it to the risk-assessment?

Thank you

Comment: select-keys is your friend to do copying http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/select-keys

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions, which may or may not apply.

1. The Clojure idiom for *no value* is `nil`. Use it.
2. Present the `asset` as a flat map. The mixture of position and
   keyword arguments is confusing and vulnerable to changes in what
   makes an asset valid.
3. As [@Symfrog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25895707/1562315) suggests, separate  the validation of the asset from its
   association with a risk assessment.
4. Don't bother to keep `:current-ia-ref` as an entry in a risk
   assessment. It is just an asset count.
5. Pull out the default entries for an asset into a map in plain sight.
   You can change your assumed defaults as you wish.

This gives us something like the following (untested):

```
(def asset-defaults {:confidentiality 3, :integrity 3, :availability 3})

(defn asset-valid? [asset] (every? asset [:name :description :owner]))

(defn add-asset [risk-assessment asset]
  (if (asset-valid? asset)
    (update-in
      risk-assessment
      [:assets]
      conj (assoc
             (merge asset asset-defaults)
             :ia-ref (inc (count (:assets risk-assessment)))
             :vulns []))))
```

---

**Responses to Comments**

*`:current-ia-ref` isn't a count. If an asset is deleted it shouldn't reduce `:current-is-ref`.*

Then (4) does not apply.

*I'm not sure of the pertinence of your statement that the Clojure idiom for no value is nil. Could explain further in this context please?*

Quoting [Differences with other Lisps](http://clojure.org/lisps): *In Clojure **nil** means 'nothing'. It signifies the absence of a value, of any type, and is not specific to lists or sequences*.

In this case, we needn't give `:author` or `:notes` empty string values.

*'Flat map': are you talking about the arguments into the function, if so then I agree.*

Yes.

*I'm not sure why you define an `asset-valid?` function. That seems to exceed the original need somewhat: and personally I prefer ensuring only valid assets can be created rather than checking after the fact.*

Your `add-asset` function uses the structure of its argument list to make sure that *risk-assessment*, *name*, *description*, *owner*, and *categories* are present (I forgot to check for *categories*). If you move to presenting the data as a map - whether as a single argument or by destructuring - you lose this constraint. So you have to check the data explicitly (whether to do so in a separate function is moot). But there are benefits:

- You can check for more than the presence of certain arguments.
- You don't have to remember what order the arguments are in.

*Wouldn't your version mean that if I decided to make asset a record in future I'd have to change all the code that called add-asset?*

No. A record behaves as a map - it implements `IPersistentMap`. You'd have to change `make-asset`, obviously.

*... whereas my approach the details of what an asset is is hidden?*

In what sense are the contents of an asset hidden? An asset is a map required to have particular keys, and likely to have several other particular keys. Whether the asset is 'really' a record doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for the response.


:current-ia-ref isn't a count. If an asset is deleted it shouldn't reduce :current-is-ref.

Comment: I'm not sure of the pertinence of your statement that the Clojure idiom for no value is nil. Could explain further in this context please?<br/>

Comment: 'Flat map': are you talking about the arguments into the function, if so then I agree.<br/>

Comment: :current-ia-ref isn't a count. If an asset is deleted it shouldn't reduce :current-ia-ref.

Comment: I did consider splitting them originally but looking at @Symfrog's suggested change confirmed my opinion that doing so actually makes the code much more complicated.
That said I do like the look of your fragment, although I'm not sure why you define an asset-valid? function. That seems to exceed the original need somewhat: and personally I prefer ensuring only valid assets can be created rather than checking after the fact.

Comment: Wouldn't your version mean that if I decided to make asset a record in future I'd have to change all the code that called add-asset, whereas my approach the details of what an asset is is hidden?

Answer (score 0):

A core principle of Clojure (and any other Lisp dialect) is to create small composable functions.

It is not a problem if an asset is created outside of a risk assessment as long as the asset is not exposed to code that is expecting a fully formed asset before it has been added to a risk assessment.

So I would suggest the following (untested):

```
(defn add-asset-ra
  [{:keys [current-ia-ref] :as risk-assessment} asset]
  (let [ia-ref (if current-ia-ref
                 (inc current-ia-ref)
                 1)] 
    (->  risk-assessment
         (assoc :current-ia-ref ia-ref)
         (update-in [:assets] #(conj % (assoc asset :ia-ref ia-ref))))))

(defn make-asset
  [name description owner categories
   & {:keys [author notes confidentiality integrity availability]
      :or   {author "" notes "" confidentiality 3 integrity 3 availability 3}}]
  {:name name
   :desc description
   :owner owner
   :categories categories
   :author author
   :notes notes
   :confidentiality confidentiality
   :integrity integrity
   :availability availability
   :vulns []})
```

You may also find the [Schema](http://github.com/Prismatic/schema) library useful to validate the shape of function arguments.

Comment: Thank you: I did consider splitting them but didn't because, as your code demonstrates, the result is more complicated code.